# Covariance of fused poses. Should it be normalised by the number of poses?

Tags: sensor-fusion, pose, estimation, uncertainty, gaussian

I came across this paper from T. Barfoot and P. Furgale:
"Associating Uncertainty With Three-Dimensional Poses for Use in Estimation Problems"
Link: http://ncfrn.mcgill.ca/members/pubs/barfoot_tro14.pdf

where in Section IV.A is explained that if I have a list of $K$ measurements $x_k$ affected by zero-mean Gaussian noise $\{x_1, \Sigma_1\},\{x_2, \Sigma_2\}, ... ,\{x_K, \Sigma_K\}$ then the mean and covariance of the fusion of such measurements $\{\bar{x},\Sigma\}$ can be found in closed form:
\begin{equation}
\bar{x} = \Sigma \sum_{k=1}^K\Sigma_k^{-1}x_k,\quad\quad \Sigma = \Bigg(\sum_{k=1}^K\Sigma_k^{-1}\Bigg)^{-1}
\end{equation}

While the computation for the mean seems correct, I'm not totally convinced that $\Sigma$ is the true covariance of the fused measurements, because there is no normalisation against K, so the more measurements are present, the smaller the covariance will be.

Let's consider the simplest case where I have two identical scalar measurements with two identical (co)variance values
\begin{equation}
\{x_1 = 1, \Sigma_1 = 4\}, \{x_2 = 1, \Sigma_2 = 4\}
\end{equation}

In that case, the mean would be obviously $\bar{x} = 1$, but the covariance would be halved: $\Sigma = (\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4})^{-1} = 2$.

Now, I understand that mere fact that there are two measurements instead of one gives a sort of confirmation that the true mean might be $1$, however I'd expect that the covariance would be still the same as the other two measurements, i.e. $\Sigma = \Sigma_1 = \Sigma_2$, because the second measurement is not bringing any additional information over the previous one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no, there shouldn't be a normalizing constant, because the uncertainty *should* decrease as we get additional independent measurements.
I'll use an example to explain this mathematically and then I'll try to give some high-level understanding of why that's the case.

## Simple example: Averaging random variables

Say we want to measure some quantity (e.g., room temperature) using a thermometer.
Furthermore, let's model the thermometer using a Gaussian random variable $\underline{y}$, where the error is given by $\underline{y} - x\sim\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma_{y}^{2})$, and $x$ is the true (unknown) temperature we're interested in measuring (note that I use underlines $\underline{(\cdot)}$ to denote a *random variable*).
Then each measurement $y_{i}\leftarrow \underline{y}$ is an **independent** *realization/sample* of this random variable.
The random variable can be rewritten as $\underline{y} - y_{i}\sim(0,\sigma_{y}^{2})$, which is useful for the derivation below.

To estimate the true temperature $x$, we need an [*estimator*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimator), which can be thought of as a function of the observations $y_{i}$ sampled from the random variables $\underline{y}_{i}$.
One possible estimator is the *average* estimator, given by
$$
\underline{\hat{x}} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\underline{y}_{i}.
$$
The estimate $\hat{x}$ is then the mean of the estimator $\underline{\hat{x}}$
$$
\hat{x}
=
\mathbb{E}[\underline{\hat{x}}]
=
\mathbb{E}\left[
   \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\underline{y}_{i}
\right]
=
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}[\underline{y}_{i}]
=
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_{i}
$$
where $\mathbb{E}[\cdot]$ is the [expectation operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value).
The variance on the estimator $\hat{\sigma}^{2}$ is then
$$
\hat{\sigma}^{2}
=
\operatorname{Var}[\underline{\hat{x}}]
=
\operatorname{Var}\left[
   \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\underline{y}_{i}
\right]
=
\frac{1}{n^{2}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\operatorname{Var}[\underline{y}_{i}]
=
\frac{1}{n^{2}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sigma_{y}^{2},
$$
which uses the [(co)variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance) rules and assumes measurements are independent.
Without this assumption, the result wouldn't hold.

Note that the covariance is independent of the measurements, and is rather only dependent on the measurements' covariance $\sigma_{y}^{2}$, which is usually a property of the sensor.
So, regardless of the sensor measurements (even if they're all identical), the covariance will decrease.
This property is specific to Gaussian random variables passed through linear functions (e.g., the averaging operator) and, in general, doesn't hold for other arbitrary estimators.

The above results are the same results you presented in your question.
I won't go into more details into about estimators and state-estimation, but more info can be found on [these slides](https://stanford.edu/class/ee363/lectures/estim.pdf).
However, I'll try to give some insight into why the results make sense.

## Why does the covariance decrease?

It may be counterintuitive that the estimate could have a smaller covariance than the measurements it's computing the estimate from.
However, the answer is somewhat related to the [law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers), where the more measurements you have, the closer you get to the true distribution.

This also makes sense intuitively, even in real life.
For example, say you read the room temperature from the wall thermometer, and you're not so convinced.
So you take another thermometer and see *identical* measurement.
Wouldn't that give you confidence that the measurement was true in the first place?
This feeling of *confidence* is a reduction in uncertainty.

> I'd expect that the covariance would be still the same as the other two measurements, i.e. $\Sigma = \Sigma_{1} = \Sigma_{2}$, because the second measurement is not bringing any additional information over the previous one.

Actually, the mere *presence* of another **independent** measurement is additional information that reduces uncertainty.
It's important that the measurements are independent. Otherwise, the new measurements are correlated to some older measurements, which is uninformative (i.e., we *already* got similar information).

Comment: Better answer couldn't have been given, thank you. Yes, the key thing is the independence assumption on the measurements. It is easier and intuitive to think that two measurements taken from two different thermometers are independent, less so if they are two readings from the same thermometer. Often, in practice it is just assumed each measurement a sensor provides is independent from the others, because calculation is simpler that way, but most likely this is not really true.